# WSWS7263E: The following exception occured : org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP(503) Unavailable address

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have a web service(WebService1) that calls another web service (WebService2), I deployed the WebService1 on WebSphere(WAS 8.0.0.5), when I am trying to access the WebService1 I am getting this error:

> WSWS7263E: The following exception occurred :
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP(503) Unavailable address: "address of
>   WebService2"

when I searched about that, I found it might have been caused because the server is too busy. 
but in this situation, the server is not busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching a lot, I find out that I must Set the class loader policy to Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) at the module level. It works for me sufficiently:

1. In the administrative console, click Applications > Application
   Types > WebSphere enterprise applications > application_name >
   Manage modules>webmodule_name.
2. Select Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) from the drop down list.
3. Click OK, and then Save to save your changes.
4. Click OK, and then Save to save your changes.

Deploy and run an application EAR file with a third-party JAX-WS implementation on WebSphere Application Server.